# Can I do anything to have my iPod Touch (2nd gen) louder?

Tags: ipod-touch, audio

To me, It's quite difficult to understand podcast when there is some noise around, for instance in noisy subway. I think I've read something about the weak output sound level of the iPod touch 2nd gen...

Is there any means to increase the sound of poscast on that device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly on the iPod, I don't think so, if your sound settings are maxed.

Try

> **Settings** > **iPod** > **Volume Limit** : Off

and

> **Settings** > **iPod** > **Sound Check** : Off

---

On iTunes, go to the "Info" window of the podcast audio file, and in the **Option** tab, try to see if you can set the audio volume to 200%. I know it works on music, but it should also be available for the podcasts.